# при переборе json-ответа у меня выходит ошибка Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: points.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, api

```
Доброе утро.При переборе json-ответа у меня выходит ошибка Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: points.forEach is not a function.
```

Помогите ,пожалуйста, с решением этой проблемы.

```
 async function getUser() {
        const response = await fetch("https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&apikey=c89368db-e7f4-4942-835a-1c7df2f555ce&geocode=Москва, улица Новый Арбат, дом 24", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json" }
        });
       const points = await response.json();
        points.forEach((item)=>{console.log(item)});
    
        }
        getUser();
```

Comment: Потому что вы применяете метод массива к points. А приходит не массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значит `points` не то, что вы ожидаете. Посмотрите во-первых в консоли что на самом деле лежит  в `points` и что на самом деле приходит в `response` например. Также можно это посмотреть в панели разработчика во вкладке Network

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого возможно надо будет чинить именно сам запрос. Возможно он просто некорректен. А может вы не учли, что возвращается объект  **с ключом response** и другими вложенностями, а не сразу массив

Comment: Алексей спасибо! Координаты получил, но выглядит как то не аккуратно: array=points.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember;
   array.forEach(item =>{console.log(item.GeoObject.Point)});         Может подскажете как сделать по-лучше?)

Comment: Да нормально. Деваться-то некуда из-за вложенности......  Считаю даже вдвойне верно , т.к. это правильно вынести нужный массив в переменную и потом в цикле работать с короткой переменной. Так что имхо всё ок